# How to validate for step by step registration form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using below code for a step-by-step registration form, but when I click on the *next* button all fields should be mandatory, it wont go for next step when I didn't fill out all the fields, please suggest me its very important.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<header style="background:white;height:100px;">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6">
<img src="logo.png">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform" method="POST">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Contact Details</li>
        <li>Address Details</li>
        <li>Personal Details</li>
        <li>identity Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required/>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" />
        <input type="text" name="altr" placeholder="Alternate Mobile" />
        <select>
        <option>Select Gender</option>
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>

        </select>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
        <select class="chosen-select">
        <option>Select State</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <select>
        <option>Select District</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <select>
        <option>Select Constitution</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <select>
        <option>Select Mandal</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <select>
        <option>Select Pincode</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Date of Birth" />
        <select>
        <option>Select Marital Status</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <select>
        <option>Select Education</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <select>
        <option>Select Languages</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <select>
        <option>Select Experience</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Id Proof-Aadhaar card" />
        <select>
        <option>Select Blood Group</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <select>
        <option>Two Wheeler</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>      
        </select>
        <label> Photo:</label><input type="file" name="phone"  />
        <label>Signature:</label><input type="file" name="phone" />
        <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="next action-button" value="Submit"  />
    </fieldset>

</form>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>

/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/
    background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
    background: 
        linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), 
        url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 24.33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}
#msform select{
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
label{
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #f50a69;
}
</style>

<script>


//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})


</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [be specific with your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please solve for first step its very very urgent please.

Answer (score 0):

jquery **key-press** event launch on `keyup` function.  You can check in this function whether it is valid now or not!

Comment: i didnt get you how to use it can you please modify in my code please its very  important for me